# NUL entry in syslog?

Tags: linux, syslog, crash

My servers went down on the 30th. It just came back online today. At first I thought it was the router because the router the server is connected to is a bit squirrely but when I checked syslog I have `NUL` entries in the down time. The log shows everything as being normal on the 30th and then all of a sudden `NUL` entries for about 2 lines before today's entry where it shows a normal bootup. Is there anyway for me to further diagnose the problem? When I say I have `NUL` entries I mean I have the ascii code 0 `NUL` character.

Comment: Hard to say, though if a server crashed (or was compromised) there could easily be wacky entries in a logfile. One step would be to look if the syslog daemon wrote a `*.core` file anywhere, and then to `gdb` that to see if a `bt` shows anything unusual.