# Characters like @ at shutdown

Tags: linux, shutdown

On the linux distros I use, debian and fedora, and on the laptops I have, when I shutdown, I see @ or sometimes other characters, on the console (next to normal sector clean /dev/xxx message) and I didn't find answers (search engines find shutdowns problem only) anywhere I searched.

Comment: Is it similar to this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/477537/117549 ?

Comment: I think not, because I don't have fs and syslog corruption, and I don't have any crashes (I don't have my laptop now so I can't see the log again until this evening french hour) But I didn't remembered to see theses @ in the log, I saw @ on the console in the shutdown procedure (before powerdown but after the desktop stops)

Comment: I inspected my dmesg and the logs and I didn't see any @, but I continue to see a variable number of @ on the console at shutdown.

Comment: Update : I don't know why but now, the problem is solved on every system I have