# Ubuntu is freezing - why and what does this symbol mean ^@?

Tags: ubuntu

```
Jul 3 15:58:01 nusik-ryzen CRON[8641]: (root) CMD (pgrep xmr-stak> /dev/null || cd /xmr-stak && ./xmr-stak) 
Jul 3 15:58:01 nusik-ryzen CRON[8642]: (root) CMD (pgrep xmrig> /dev/null || /xmrig/build/xmrig) 
Jul 3 15:58:01 nusik-ryzen CRON[8639]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output) ^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@
Jul 3 16:09:23 nusik-ryzen rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="8.16.0" x-pid="969" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start 
Jul 3 16:09:23 nusik-ryzen rsyslogd-2222: command 'KLogPermitNonKernelFacility' is currently not permitted - did you already set it via a RainerScript command (v6+ config)? [v8.16.0 try http://www.rsyslog.com/e/2222 ]
```

Comment: `^@` is the null byte. A sequence of them usually means a file was shortened while another process was still writing to it, so the missing part was replaced by nulls.

Comment: Relating: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/477537/system-crash-strange-chars-in-syslog

Comment: thanks, so that's a symptom, not a reason.

Comment: @JeffSchaller how to find what is the reason?